# No route matches {:action=>"show", :guide_id=>#, :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-routes

I know the question is asked number of times and I am also having same error but could'nt fix it.

I am getting below error if I try to edit my record:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"guide/packages", :guide_id=>#
<GuidePackage id: 1, user_id: 3, title: "Paris to london", city: nil, 
price_per_adult: 2.44, price_per_children: 7.88, description: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX", 
created_at: "2017-04-20 20:01:58", updated_at: "2017-04-20 20:01:58">, 
:id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

My new action is:

```
  def new
    @guide_package = @guide.guide_packages.new
  end
```

My edit action  is:

```
  def edit
    @guide_package = GuidePackage.find(params[:id])
  end
```

The index from where I click edit link:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_guide_guide_package_path(@guide, guide_package), title: "Edit" %>
```

My method is which I find guide user:

```
  def set_guide
    @guide = User.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])
  end
```

Routes are:

```
           guide_guide_packages GET      /guide/:guide_id/packages(.:format)                 guide/packages#index
                                POST     /guide/:guide_id/packages(.:format)                 guide/packages#create
        new_guide_guide_package GET      /guide/:guide_id/packages/new(.:format)             guide/packages#new
       edit_guide_guide_package GET      /guide/:guide_id/packages/:id/edit(.:format)        guide/packages#edit
            guide_guide_package GET      /guide/:guide_id/packages/:id(.:format)             guide/packages#show
                                PATCH    /guide/:guide_id/packages/:id(.:format)             guide/packages#update
                                PUT      /guide/:guide_id/packages/:id(.:format)             guide/packages#update
                                DELETE   /guide/:guide_id/packages/:id(.:format)             guide/packages#destroy
```

My form for new and edit:

```
<%= form_for [:guide, @guide_package], :multipart => true do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

My all routes are:

```
  namespace :guide do
    resources :guides, :path => '/' do
      resources :packages
    end
  end
```

The new works perfectly and creates the records as well but I am unable to edit my form using new form.

Comment: In your edit link, what are the values of `@guide` and `guide_package`?

Comment: @mmichael its `/guide/muhammad-hassan/packages/1/edit` so @guide: `muhammad-hassan` and guide_package: `1`. I am finding `muhammad-hassan` from method name: `@guide = User.friendly.find(params[:guide_id])`. Are my routes are ok? I mean nested routes for form_for?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<%= form_for [@guide, @guide_package], :multipart => true do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: it says: undefined method `user_guide_package_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000003cb9c80>:0x007fdde89613b0>

Comment: Even in edit method: `@guide_package = @guide.guide_packages.new` render the new form but if i do the: `@guide_package = @guide.guide_packages.where(id: params[:id]).first` the same error comes up in edit with the error stated in question.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced some similar issue. My solution was:

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_guide_guide_package_path(:guide_id => @guide.id,  :id => guide_package.id), title: "Edit" %>
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Still the same error. The above stated error is coming in: `<%= form_for [:guide, @guide_package], :multipart => true do |f| %>`